# How to extract noun adjective pairs from a sentence

Tags: python, nltk

I wish to extract noun-adjective pairs from this `sentence`. So, basically I want something like :
`(Mark,sincere) (John,sincere)`.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
sentence = "Mark and John are sincere employees at Google."
print ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
```

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030009/how-to-extract-the-verbs-and-all-corresponding-adverbs-from-a-text

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spacy's [POS tagging](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#pos-tagging) would be a better than `NLTK`. It's faster and better. Here is an example of what you want to do

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'Mark and John are sincere employees at Google.')
noun_adj_pairs = []
for i,token in enumerate(doc):
    if token.pos_ not in ('NOUN','PROPN'):
        continue
    for j in range(i+1,len(doc)):
        if doc[j].pos_ == 'ADJ':
            noun_adj_pairs.append((token,doc[j]))
            break
noun_adj_pairs
```

**output**

`[(Mark, sincere), (John, sincere)`]

Comment: Spacy is better than nltk.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a doubt about what is to be done if the adjective describing the noun happens to be appear before the noun?

Comment: @AarushiAiyyar take a look at dependency parsing in Spacy. https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#dependency-parse

Comment: "Photos under low lighting is poor - both front and back cameras". For this sentence the expected output would be [(Photos,poor),(lighting,low)]. But the output that I get is [(Photos, low), (lighting, poor)]. What do I do?

Comment: again, check dependency parsing.

Comment: The last line should be:
print (noun_adj_pairs)
not noun_adj_pairs