# How to extract noun and adjective pairs including conjunctions

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

### Background

I would like to extract nouns and adjectives pairs using NLP libraries, such as spaCy.

The expected input and output are below.

```
The pink, beautiful, and small flowers are blown away.
{'flowers':['pink', 'beautiful', 'small']}

I got a red candy and an interesting book.
{'candy':['red'], 'book':['interesting']}
```

### Problem

Following the answer to a similar question, [How to extract noun adjective pairs from a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166071/how-to-extract-noun-adjective-pairs-from-a-sentence/49166586), I executed the program with my inputs.

However, it returned no output.

```
[]
```

### Code

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp('The beautiful and small flowers are blown away.')
noun_adj_pairs = []
for i,token in enumerate(doc):
    if token.pos_ not in ('NOUN','PROPN'):
        continue
    for j in range(i+1,len(doc)):
        if doc[j].pos_ == 'ADJ':
            noun_adj_pairs.append((token,doc[j]))
            break
print(noun_adj_pairs)
```

### Trial

I've tried to write a new code but still, I'm stack with how to handle adjectives with conjunctions.

```
input
I got a red candy and an interesting book.
output
{'candy': 'red', 'book': 'interesting'}

input
The pink, beautiful, and small flowers are blown away.
output
{'flowers': 'small'}
```

trial code

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp('I got a red candy and an interesting book.')
noun_adj_pairs = {}
for word in doc:
    if word.pos_ == 'ADJ' and word.dep_ != "cc":
        if word.head.pos_ =="NOUN":
            noun_adj_pairs[str(word.head.text)]=str(word.text)

print(noun_adj_pairs)
```

### Environment

Python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to try [`noun_chunks`](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#noun-chunks):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp('I got a red candy and an interesting and big book.')

noun_adj_pairs = {}
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    adj = []
    noun = ""
    for tok in chunk:
        if tok.pos_ == "NOUN":
            noun = tok.text
        if tok.pos_ == "ADJ":
            adj.append(tok.text)
    if noun:
        noun_adj_pairs.update({noun:adj})

# expected output
noun_adj_pairs
{'candy': ['red'], 'book': ['interesting', 'big']}
```

Should you wish to include conjunctions:

```
noun_adj_pairs = {}
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    adj = []
    noun = ""
    for tok in chunk:
        if tok.pos_ == "NOUN":
            noun = tok.text
        if tok.pos_ == "ADJ" or tok.pos_ == "CCONJ":
            adj.append(tok.text)
    if noun:
        noun_adj_pairs.update({noun:" ".join(adj)})

noun_adj_pairs
{'candy': 'red', 'book': 'interesting and big'}
```