# Finding the nouns in a sentence given the context in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, textblob

How to find the nouns in a sentence regarding the context? I am using the `nltk` library as follows:

```
text = 'I bought a vintage car.'
text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
result = nltk.pos_tag(text)
result = [i for i in result if i[1] == 'NN']

#result = [('vintage', 'NN'), ('car', 'NN')]
```

The problem with this script is that it considers `vintage` as a noun, which can be true, but given the context, it is an adjective.

How can we achieve this task?

**Appendix:** Using `textblob`, we get "vintage car" as the noun:

```
!python -m textblob.download_corpora
from textblob import TextBlob
txt = "I bought a vintage car."
blob = TextBlob(txt)
print(blob.noun_phrases) #['vintage car']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting all Nouns from a text file using nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587667/extracting-all-nouns-from-a-text-file-using-nltk)

Comment: @SurajShourie It does not. The proposed solution in that thread provides "vintage car" as the noun.

Comment: Well, it certainly is the subject.  I suppose you can parse the multi-word subject to figure out that only one of them is always a noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [spacy](https://spacy.io/) might solve your task. Try this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

def analyze(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    for token in doc:
        print(token.text, token.pos_)

analyze("I bought a vintage car.")
print()
analyze("This old wine is a vintage.")
```

Output

```
I PRON
bought VERB
a DET
vintage ADJ <- correctly identified as adjective
car NOUN
. PUNCT

This DET
old ADJ
wine NOUN
is AUX
a DET
vintage NOUN  <- correctly identified as noun
. PUNCT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spacy` and [noun_chunks](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#noun-chunks) to separate out the nouns:

```
import spacy # tested with version 3.6.1
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp('I bought a vintage car.')
noun = []
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    for tok in chunk:
        if tok.pos_ == "NOUN":
            noun.append(tok.text)
print(noun)
```

which prints out:

> ['car']

However, if you wish to extract both the nouns and the adjectives you can try this as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64422463/12317368):

```
noun_adj_pairs = {}
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    adj = []
    noun = ""
    for tok in chunk:
        if tok.pos_ == "NOUN":
            noun = tok.text
        if tok.pos_ == "ADJ" or tok.pos_ == "CCONJ": # accounts for both adjective and conjunctions
            adj.append(tok.text)
    if noun:
        noun_adj_pairs.update({noun:" ".join(adj)})
```

which prints out:

> {'car': 'vintage'}